# Is it possible to ensure if a window is reached to the destination position and size using applescript or accessibility API?

Tags: macos, cocoa, applescript

**Goal: Ensure the app's window is moved to the destination's position and size and also make sure the entire window is showed on the screen.**

I have following script, it sometimes works and sometimes don't.

For the sake of simplicity I hardcoded values. Two things script is doing,

It sets position & size based on a certain parameters then it retrieve final size value. If calculated size is less than app's window minimum size then take minimize size(winWidth, winHeight) of the window and use this for positioning and sizing of the window to ensure the complete window is shown on the screen.

screen size - 1920 X 1080,
menu bar height - 24,
dock height - 61

visible empty space screen height - 1835 and the script is suppose to show the window bottom half

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Craft"
        delay 0.1
        tell window 1 to set position to {1835 / 2, 25}
        tell window 1 to set size to {(1835) / 2, 994}
    end tell
    delay 0.1
    
    set {winWidth, winHeight} to size of the first window of application process "Craft"
    
    tell application process "Craft"
        delay 0.1
        tell window 1 to set position to {1835 - winWidth, 25}
        tell window 1 to set size to {(1835) / 2, 994}
        
    end tell
    delay 0.1
    return winWidth
end tell
```

firstly I am not quite sure if this is how to calculate it but looking at Math it should work. Secondly, no idea when why it stops working but rarely.

Work around - I am running the above script more than once to fix the issue but still have some hiccups with it.

Comment: Can you describe what the hiccups are, and what you mean when you say it stops working ?  What happens that isn't supposed to in these instances, and what doesn't happen that you expected ought to ?  And how are you choosing the positions you want the windows to end up in ?  Can you describe it, as you said those values are just example values, but if this is going to get mathsy, a clear description will very likely help bypass some of the arithmetic because of how certain things work in terms of positioning windows on screen in consideration of the menu bar and dock etc.

Comment: @CJK I have added more details to the question. The script is suppose to show bottom half of the screen and hardcoded values represent the values that is suppose to show window to bottom half. Regarding hiccups, window moves and show as bottom half but sometimes it doesnt move at all.

Comment: Is the script in the question not working? Does the size also not change? Have you tried talking to the same window, everything inside `tell window 1 of application process "Craft"`? Have you tried set size, get minsize, set position (without the first set position and the second set size)?

Comment: You could make the script do multiple attempts.

Comment: To clarify, when you say _"the script is suppose to show the window bottom half"_, do you mean that you're trying to position the window so that it occupies the entire lower-half of your screen, like [this](https://imgur.com/Tzsa9Uh)...?

Comment: @CJK thats right and just above the dock

Comment: @Willeke it didn't made any difference when I put everything inside tell window 1. I was wondering if I can use like a while loop like run the script until it reaches to the expected size and position

Comment: Yes, a loop could work. Is Craft the frontmost app? Have you tried bigger delays at the right places (ask yourself why you add a delay)? Is the script in the question also not working and how?